# minikube not able to start with error in driver during machine creation

Tags: docker, virtualbox, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to install minikube on windows7  with minikube v0.13.1 + oracle virtual box 5.0. When I try to start:

```
minikube start
```

I am facing stopping with error:

> error creation in driver during machine / cannot open cache/iso/minikube.0.x.iso / error getting state for host:machine doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Without having more information, you should try to delete the cached ISO at `~/.minikube/cache/iso`.  Then run `minikube delete`